# Excel formula - print all the true condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
=IF(A1="ONE","PRINT1",IF(B1="TWO","PRINT2",IF(C1="THREE","PRINT3")))
```

If all the conditions are true, the expected output is: `PRINT1,PRINT2,PRINT3`

But I am getting `PRINT1` only.

Thanks

Comment: please share some sample data and expected output. What would be the desired result if only two out of three conditions are met? e.g. if A1=ONE, B1=TWO but C1=FOUR, do you want to return PRINT1 and PRINT2 except PRINT3?

Answer (score 1):

OR,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(A1="ONE","PRINT1 "," ")&IF(B1="TWO","PRINT2 "," ")&IF(C1="THREE","PRINT3 "," "))," ",",")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another option:

[image]

And without "Two":

[image]

Comment: as shown in this picture , i am expecting this answer only ..but while iam trying this it shows print1 only.why?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use a condition, you are excluding options. If you want to include all the options:

IF(A1="ONE",IF(B1="TWO",IF(C1="THREE","PRINT1,PRINT2,PRINT3","PRINT1,PRINT2"), IF(C1="THREE","PRINT1,PRINT3","PRINT1")),IF(B1="TWO",IF(C1="THREE","PRINT2,PRINT3","PRINT2"), "PRINT3"))

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the reply. I hope it will help. I am able to understand this. can you please explain this

Comment: What do you want from me to explain?